# Node.JS with domain aliases

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache

Currently we have an Node.JS server with different domainnames. That domainnames are domains from our customers which points to our server with a CNAME and shows their own webshop.

So, let's say our domain is webshop.com and we have 2 customers: customer1.com and customer2.eu. Both domains have a CNAME on @ and WWW to webshop.com

Currently we have Apache running with all those domains in a separate config file. The sites are rewriting to localhost:3000/extern/customer-1 where the slug is an unique name based on the shopname. Since we are using RewriteRule the address stays customer1.com, but visitors can see a fast redirect (301).
We are also using Let's Encrypt for https.

This is how a default domain config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName customer1.com
  ServerAlias www.customer1.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://customer1.com/$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName customer1.com
  ServerAlias www.customer1.com
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^/$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/extern/customer-1 [P]
  RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/extern/customer-1/$1 [P]
  RewriteRule ^/(.+) http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P]

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/customer1.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/customer1.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/customer1.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

### The problem

Currently there is something wrong with Apache/Node.JS so all pages shows an `Cannot GET /extern/customer-1` and also on our main domain after a refresh (or redirect).
Is there a way to refactor this whole structure and make a automatized process for adding domains? (We now added all domains manually.) Our frontend app is written in Angular, so maybe there are some solutions?